# Release Management with ClickOnce

Tags: ms-release-management

Recently I have been trying to use Microsoft Release Management 2013 to deploy a click once application, but I can not find any "Tools" or "Actions" inside the inventory section.

How can I deploy this? Is it possible? Do I need to create a custom action with proper parameters to deploy this?

On the other hand, clickonce is published using msbuild, so is it possible that I cannot deploy this using only release management.

Maybe I need to use a custom TFS template to create publish and later move this one to a webserver using release management?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I think it's clear.. isn't?